WMS layer editing capabilities
I'm currently writing my thesis with QGIS. I have a WMS layer that shows many plots and the classification of these plots. I need to edit this layer so that only plots with classification I-III are included.
Is there a tool/bot/AI that reflects the classification contours to a layer that I can edit (e.g. SHP) or will I need to manually redraw a large area?

Can you ask the WMS service provider for the data? Or is it available as a WFS service, then you can download the data

see https://blog.ianturton.com/ogc/2022/02/11/WMS-and-WFS.html

WMS specification does not support editing through the interface.      You may be able to apply some classification by sending a custom style (SLD).

You can filter your WMS data so it only displays the classifications I-III.
This stackexchange question discusses how to do this with QGIS and QGIS server.
This stackexchange question discusses how to do this with QGIS and Geoserver.

As a general rule, you can't edit WMS/WFS/WCS layers. You can, however, try to download the extent of your region of interest from the server to a local file (if the provider allows this) and then edit this local file. To download it, load the WMS/WFS/WCS connection as layer in QGIS. In the layer panel, right click the layer -> Export -> Save As...
Be aware: you ask about WMS, thus raster layers. It's a bit confusing because you want to edit it as vector layer (SHP). If you want to extract contour lines or contour polygons from your raster, see here how to do that.


WFS and WCS can be editable if the service provider has enabled transactional capabilities.
